# Rotate bitmap by using a array

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory, pixel

In my app i have an int array which contains all of the colors of my bitmap by calling: `bitmap.getPixels(intArr....)`

I would like a way to rotate this image etc 90 degrees. I know this can be done with a matrix and a canvas, but i've also heard this way is quite memory inefficient. Like this example:

```
Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, config);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(mRotation,source.getWidth()/2,source.getHeight()/2);
canvas.drawBitmap(source, matrix, new Paint());
```

Im wondering if/how a rotation via the int array could be done, by looping though all the elements in the array and apply some kind of algorithm, and if this is more memory efficient than a matrix.

Thanks!

Comment: use a Matrix (or Canvas.rotate), it's a best approach

Comment: Why did you add the tag "outofmemoryexception"? Does this exception get thrown?

Comment: Yes, sometimes when rotating a bigger bitmap!

Answer (score 1):

Can rotate without using canvas,

```
 public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap src, float degree) {
        // create new matrix
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // setup rotation degree
        matrix.postRotate(degree);

        // return new bitmap rotated using matrix
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
```